# Implementing Google Calendar API to get a list of events in ASP.NET core

Tags: .net-core, google-calendar-api

I followed the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet), except that I implemented it in a web app, and everything works fine in localhost, when I call the API to get calendar events for a give date, I get the events list back. However when I deploy to my test site I get a `502 Bad Gateway` response, making the same call as in localhost.

Has anybody experienced the same? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If it works on localhost and not on deployment, it just means there are configurations which haven't been met. Check this [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) about setting up web apps using ASP.NET.

> In order to run the following code successfully, you must first add a
>   redirect URI to your project in the Google API Console. Since you will
>   use FlowMetadata and its default settings, set the redirect URI to
>   your_site/AuthCallback/IndexAsync.